# I Solemnly Swear That I Am Up To No Good

Tags: riddle, mathematics, anagram, chemistry

Quite simple. Find the odd one out, follow the instruction to give you a letter and then give me the code word.

Two pieces of advice first:

1) They gradually get harder (in my opinion)

2) Don't forget to check the tags!

i) Beijing ; Moscow ; Italy ; Vienna ; Sicily ; *Shanghai (added to clarify)*

(First letter - use this letter twice)

ii) O ; Q ; M ; S ; U ; *C (added to clarify)*

Hint:

> This one is visual, not phonetic.

(use the odd one out)

iii) Flock ; Squabble ; Band ; Parliament ; Clowder (First letter)

iv) Monopoly ; Battleships ; Articulate ; Trivial Pursuit ; Scrabble

(Use the last letter)

v) Giraffe ; Horse ; Sheep ; Cow ; Bison

(First letter)

vi) H ; U ; C ; I ; O ; S ; Y ; W ; V ; K ; N ; B ; P (You need the letter that is *missing*)

vii) 4 ; 6 ; 17 ; 32 ; 50 ; 100 ; 101 ; 245

(Sum of digits minus one gives position in the alphabet e.g. 2 = A)

Comment: I would recommend you remove the answers from the question itself, as it would make the puzzle useless to future viewers once it is completely solved. Once all clues are deciphered, the one who got most of the parts right can compile one complete answer that you can accept.

Comment: Sum of digits: 100= 1+0+0= 1. Subtracting 1 gives 0. Is it correct?

Comment: @jaydm26 There's a free clue. Can't be 100 since 0 doesn't correspond to any position in the alphabet.

Comment: @Inazuma hahaha

Comment: For vii) does the letter case make a difference?

Comment: Two pieces of advice: 1. No need to tell which parts are harder. 2. No need to tell ppl to look at the tags, they'll anyway notice eventually

Comment: @jaydm26, no difference. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. > Italy. It is the only country.
2. > M. Only letter without a curve.
3. > Clowder. Only collective noun which is not used for a bird.
4. > Battleships. Only one that is not a board game.
5. > Horse. All other have very common hoof patterns (thanks M Oehm)
6. > F. Only single letter element not present.
7. > E. Don't know why. Reason below.

The anagram is

> I I M C S H F E

Resulting in

> MISCHIEF

I solved the anagram for 7

So the code word could be

> Mischief Managed (from Harry Potter)

Comment: Correct. Any clues on the title?

Comment: It's Harry Potter

Comment: What is the actual reason for E in vii)?

Comment: 6 is the only number that cannot be written as the sum of two perfect squares.

Comment: Battleship is a boardgame...

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole thank you for pointing it out. I just had a look at the Wikipedia image and made the deduction. I think inazuma must have meant in the first form only, which was a pad and pencil game as you said.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole  I think that it might be that Battleship is a two player game?

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole Battleship is the only game in the list that cannot be played by more than 2 people.

Comment: For the second one, I thought Q since it's the only letter that isn't written in one stroke. Also, a lot of the questions' answers seem to depend on interpretation... isn't there supposed to be one answer?

Comment: battleship is the only game that uses purely luck (although this might include monopoly) sorry for the troll

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole The game is called Battleship, not Battleship***s***. Tricky...

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Neither Battleship nor Monopoly is purely luck-based.

Comment: @immibis; there are only basic skills needed to play BS, i.e. not stupid stuff

Comment: @immibis The game is also called Battleships

Comment: Italy is also the only one with no duplicate letters

Answer (score 4):

partial answer

**i)**

> Beijing, Moscow, Vienna and Shanghai are cities
>  Of course, there are cities called Italy and Sicily as well, but that's not the first thing that pop ups my mind when I think of locations with that name (rather a country and an island, respectively)

**ii)**

i'm not sure, but it might be something like

> the letter pronounced is a proper english word. oh, queue, am, as, you, see?

or, taking the hint about being a visual riddle

> it might be Q, as that one does not have any vertical axial, horizontal axial and rotational symmetry

**vi)**

> F

because

> it is the only chemical element with a single letter symbol missing from the list

Comment: Thought this one would be harder, lol.

I underestimate you all. Yes F is correct.

Comment: Your reasoning for i) is correct, but would you be able to clarify which item you are choosing (since even if your reasoning is different to mine if you've found it to be an odd one out I can't exactly mark you wrong).

Comment: well, if I really have to choose, I'd go for Italy being the odd one out, as the city Sicily is better known than the city Italy, but then this reasoning isn't really rigorous any more

Comment: Italy is the correct answer . I considered the Sicily referred to here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicily as a city, but now I see I may have just been ignorant :/

Comment: Definitely not a city.

Comment: Very embarrassing, considering I've been there.

Comment: Business Cat has cracked ii) (M)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

i)

> Beijing is the odd one out. All the others are in Europe, Beijing is in China.

ii) ***EDIT:*** New answer

> M is the odd one out. It is the only one of the letters that has corners, the others all just have curves.

iii)

> Squabble is the odd one out. The others all refer to groups of animals: a flock of sheep, a band of gorillas, a parliament of owls, a clowder of cats.

vi)

> These are all the periodic table elements with one-letter symbols. F, for fluorine, is missing.

Comment: i), ii) are logically correct, but not what I was thinking of. vi) is correct. For iii), squabble also refers to a group of animals (think seagulls).

Comment: @Inazuma I looked the names up because my first instinct was that parliament wasn't one, but you learn something new everyday.

Comment: I have refined i) and ii) - hopefully that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Beat me to it on ii) ;)

Comment: Yes!! M is correct :)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

ii)

> O is the odd one out as it is the only letter which when written on paper, starts and ends at the same point.

iv)

> Battleships is the only game in the list which is played by 2 players at a time. The others can be played by at least 4 players simultaneously. Last letter is S.

Comment: My reasoning was slightly different, but this partial answer is correct.

Comment: @Inazuma: I've taken a crack at ii)

Comment: Unfortunately O isn't the answer, I could have included D, just as easily.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

v)

> These animals, with the exception of horses, have cloven hooves. (First letter: **H**)

Comment: Correct answer, correct reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I know @Inazuma already explained his reasoning behind the answer for (vii), but another reason that

> 6 (E) is the odd one can be attributed to the fact that it is the only number divisible by 3 in the list. Well, at least that was my initial thought until I discovered his comments below :)